# How to store images inside the folder in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to save the images based on comparison. If the result of the comparison is less than 0.01 it should be in the same folder , if not a new directory should be created and the image should reside in it, if the value is not less than 0.01 it is not creating folder in which the image should save .

this is where i am checking it

```
        d2 = cv2.matchShapes(img_1,img_2,cv2.CONTOURS_MATCH_I2,1)
        if d2 <= 0.01:
```

**in this case each image is compared with the second image,the second image is compared with the third and so on. If d2 is greater than 0.01 new directory should be created and the image would be save in that category which is not happening right now.**

Any help would be appreciated

this is the code

```
visited_images = []
similarity_dict = {}
count = 0
for image_1_path in os.listdir("noise"):
    img_1 = cv2.imread(os.path.join("noise", image_1_path),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    visited_images.append(image_1_path)
    for image_2_path in os.listdir("noise"):
        if image_2_path in visited_images:
            continue
        img_2 = cv2.imread(os.path.join("noise", image_2_path),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        d2 = cv2.matchShapes(img_1,img_2,cv2.CONTOURS_MATCH_I2,1)
        if d2 <= 0.01:
            visited_images.append(image_2_path)
            if image_1_path not in similarity_dict.keys():
                count += 1
                similarity_dict[image_1_path] = [image_2_path]
                os.mkdir(os.path.join("sorted-characters", str(count)))
                cv2.imwrite(os.path.join("sorted-characters", str(count), image_1_path),img_1)
                cv2.imwrite(os.path.join("sorted-characters",  str(count), image_2_path),img_2)
                continue
            similarity_dict[image_1_path].append(image_2_path)
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join("sorted-characters", str(count), image_1_path),img_1)
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join("sorted-characters",  str(count), image_2_path),img_2)
    print(visited_images)
```

**when i am printing the visited_images it is showing all the images inside this list which means that it is visiting all the images inside the noise folder**

this is the output of noise folder

```
['1.png']
['1.png', '2.png']
['1.png', '2.png', '3.png', 'Img_219.png']
['1.png', '2.png', '3.png', 'Img_219.png', 'Img_219.png']
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The folders are not being created? The image not being saved on the folders? Is there an exception of some sort? What is the value of `image_1_path`?